# Largest product in a series

Tags: c

[Here](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler008) is the problem statement.

> Find the greatest product of K consecutive digits in the N digit
> number.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> First line contains T that denotes the number of test cases.
> First line of each test case will contain two integers N & K.
> Second line of each test case will contain a N digit integer.
>
> **Output Format**
>
> Print the required answer for each test case.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> ```
> 1≤T≤100  
> 1≤K≤7  
> K≤N≤1000
> ```
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 2
> 10 5
> 3675356291
> 10 5
> 2709360626
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> 3150
> 0
> ```

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        int n,k;
        scanf("%d%d",&n,&k);
        char a[n];
        int b[n];
        int i,j;
        long long int x=1;
    
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            scanf("%c",&a[i]);
        int index;
        long long int max=0;

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            b[i]=a[i]-'0';

        for(i=0;i<n-k;i++)
        {
            x=1;
            for(j=i;j<i+k;j++)
                x*=b[j];
            if(x>max)
            {
                max=x;
                index=i;
            }
        }

        printf("%lld\n",max);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get wrong output for many inputs and correct output for some. In short, there is some error in my code and I am not able to find it out. I'm looking for help.

> **EXAMPLE** for wrong output
>
> **INPUT**
>
> ```
> 1
> 10 5
> 1111122222
> ```
>
> **OUTPUT**
>
> ```
> 8(should be 16)
> ```

Comment: For what input do you get the wrong answer?

Comment: What makes you believe that your solution is not correct.  "Where have I gone wrong" is way too broad.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer as i said its a programming challenge and its giving me a wrong answer

Comment: @Olaf: Of course he does: the code fails to implement an answer to the question. He did not describe the failure, just that the output differs from what is expected.  Read my answer: yet another illustration of why `scanf` is the wrong tool for most parsing tasks.  I answered his question not for help on projecteuler, but for additional defiance toward `scanf` and friends

Comment: @chqrlie: "Why is my code not working" [shall include more information than just this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Also I find it plain unfair to ask for help in a programming callenge (actually: to provide that help). But, hey, maybe I'm getting old and am no more "cool" (can live without that - another sign of getting older).

Comment: @Olaf: I am probably older than you... I agree with you for the most part.  The OP is not going very far on http://projecteuler.net , a very fine site with challenging problems and quite a humbling experience when you finally get a correct answer, gain access to the forum page and read about other people's methods.  The OP is still a young programmer, he will learn a lot there.

Comment: @chqrlie: Read your profile after I commented. I do not have a problem with him asking about a programming question here (surprisingly for a programming Q&A site;-), but he apparently did no research on his own (or he does not show it here); that is my point. (I'm not the guy to have others suffer like I had back then, however).

Comment: @Olaf i did a fair bit of research but the mistake i had committed could only be solved by some third person reading it so i had no choice

Comment: I can imagine how many wasted hours `scanf()` has caused.  A bug like this is very difficult to spot.  My advice is to use `fgets()` to read lines from the input and `sscanf()` to parse them in the few cases where it would be more cumbersome to do it by hand.

Comment: Atul: You could have stripped the example down, printed what you have `scanf`ed or watched in a debugger. This is every-day practice for programming. You do not start a marathon if you cannot run at least 5km. However, might very well be the way you asked which makes me suspicious about cheating. If that, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not read the `'\n'` at the end of the first line before scanning the `n` digits of the number on the following line. Hence the first character read in the `for(i=0;i<n;i++) scanf("%c",&a[i]);` loop is not a digit, but the `'\n'` that is still sitting in the `stdin` buffer.

You should change the first `scanf` to this:

```
scanf("%d%d\n",&n,&k);
```

or read both lines with `fgets()`

Comment: it doesnt matter i guess, never had a problem before. can you explain more clearly how that would help?

Comment: It DOES matter! you read `n` digits with `scanf("%c",&a[i]);`.  Aside from the simpler alternative `a[i] = getchar();`, the problem is the first character you read is not a digit, it is the `'\n'` that `scanf("%d%d",&n,&k);` left in `stdin`.

Comment: yeah, that worked miraculously. thanks a lot. didn't dream of that being a loophole

Comment: Thank you, but I do not believe in miracles.  The correction works because it fixes a bug in your code.  If you do not understand why, you will continue misusing `scanf()` and will waste many more hours looking for similar bugs.